# Limpiar valores de un label con JS

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, bootstrap

gracias por la ayuda de antemano, lo que busco es resetear el valor de un label en IdDocente (el icono con el usuario en color verde). Por ahora le estoy pasando parámetros para mostrar, resultado de una consulta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es mi función que limpia los datos del modal:

```js
// FUNCIÓN |> Limpiar datos en modal.
function LimpiarDatos() {
    var DatosIndex = document.getElementsByClassName("LimpiarDatos");
    var DatosJSIndex = DatosIndex.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < DatosJSIndex; i++) {
        DatosIndex[i].value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-2 mb-4 justify-content-center">
<a role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
<i class="fas fa-user" style="color:gray"></i>
<span class="LimpiarDatos badge badge-success" id="DocID" style="vertical-align: top"></span>
</a>
</div>
```

Se limpian todos los inputs menos el label, alguna forma en la que pueda hacer el proceso de limpiado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si es un formulario te bastara de la siguiente manera

```
document.getElementById('Id del formulario').reset();
```

Y para limpiar un label tienes que acceeder a su contenido osea

```
document.getElementById('Id del label').innerHTML = '';
```

Comment: Gracias amigo, basado en tu ejemplo añadí la linea: DatosIndex[i].innerHTML = '' "; a mi función. Saludos